# Microsoft Graph API C# - How to update "CreatedBy" or "ModifiedBy" in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to update the CreatedBy  (Author) or ModifiedBy (Editor) field for a document in Sharepoint using GraphAPI?

I am currently using a default service account to upload documents using GraphApi, but I need to update the "CreatedBy" field.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here documents are nothing but the driveItems. If you check the driveItem resource type, you would see the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) where it is mentioned that CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy are read-only properties. So we cannot update the read-only properties.